# SQL, insert into table while calculating difference between two times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm currently using fullcalendar to make a simple calendar. My database has got three date-times:

```
start 
end
total
```

What I want is the program, as it inserts the date, to calculate the difference between start and end and add it to total. This is my SQL code for insertion:

I'm using InnoDB in MySQL.

````
session_start();

include_once './conexao.php';

$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

//Converter a data e hora do formato brasileiro para o formato do Banco de Dados
$data_start = str_replace('/', '-', $dados['start']);
$data_start_conv = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data_start));

$data_end = str_replace('/', '-', $dados['end']);
$data_end_conv = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data_end));

$query_event = "INSERT INTO events (title, name, color, start, end, total) "
        . "VALUES (:title, :name, :color, :start, :end) "
        . "SELECT DATEDIFF(':start', ':end') AS total";

$insert_event = $conn->prepare($query_event);
$insert_event->bindParam(':title', $dados['title']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':name', $dados['name']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':color', $dados['color']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':start', $data_start_conv);
$insert_event->bindParam(':end', $data_end_conv);

if ($insert_event->execute()) {
    $retorna = ['sit' => true, 'msg' => '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Evento inserido com sucesso!</div>'];
    $_SESSION['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Evento inserido com sucesso!</div>';
} else {
    $retorna = ['sit' => false, 'msg' => '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro: Evento não foi inserido com sucesso!</div>'];
}


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($retorna);```
````

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see just from looking that you must be experiencing a SQL syntax error - you can't use `INSERT...VALUES` and `INSERT...SELECT` syntax in the same query - you must use one or the other. But you don't need the `SELECT` here, you can just put the DATEDIFF function as one of the values. You also don't need quote marks round the parameters you pass to DATEDIFF.

You also can't use the same parameter name twice in PDO.

This should work better I think (although I'm not able to test it, obviously):

```
$query_event = "INSERT INTO events (title, name, color, start, end, total) "
        . "VALUES (:title, :name, :color, :start, :end, DATEDIFF(:start2, :end2))";

$insert_event = $conn->prepare($query_event);
$insert_event->bindParam(':title', $dados['title']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':name', $dados['name']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':color', $dados['color']);
$insert_event->bindParam(':start', $data_start_conv);
$insert_event->bindParam(':end', $data_end_conv);
$insert_event->bindParam(':start2', $data_start_conv);
$insert_event->bindParam(':end2', $data_end_conv);
```

P.S. If there are still other issues when you run the code you will need to explain it specifically, since you didn't mention them at the start.

Comment: I am not able to insert anything using this code, and I get no error. It may have something to do with my JS script that manages the calendar. This code: https://pastebin.com/pCawrQQP is able to insert the data and is the one I made before trying to calculate the difference

Comment: If you think the error is on the JS side, you need to debug the JS side and check whether it is even triggering the PHP to execute or not. You didn't show any of that, so I can't help you with it. But this answer should fix the issue with the PHP. Maybe you should unit-test the PHP part using something like PostMan to generate the HTTP request, and then once that is working, you can fix the client-side code to make it generate its own request correctly.

Comment: @Rui And if you think there is still an error with this query, then you need to debug it. Make sure PDO is set to throw exceptions when errors occur (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) and make sure PHP is set to log and/or echo errors (see https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/). Set that up, and then run the code again, and see what it reports back. That way you might have a better idea of how to start fixing it.

Comment: P.S. I'm far from convinced you actually _need_ this `total` column anyway. Such a value can be calculated anytime, using your "start" and "end" values which you are already storing. Relational database theory usually suggests that you don't store values which can be calculated using other stored values - instead you just perform the calculation on-demand in a SELECT query, whenever you want to see that data. (The only exception to this would be if the calculation was very slow to run, especially with large datasets. But that shouldn't be a big concern here.)

Comment: Thanks for the time given to me here, I'll for sure set up error handling as I did forget to do so. I'll also look into the SELECT query further and see if I can make the calculation on the go with a HTML table

Comment: Good idea. You could just have a query such as `SELECT DATEDIFF(start, end) as total FROM events` for example, and run that (or a version of that) whenever you need to see totals. Then you would not need to worry about storing it in the database.

Comment: That would work but I need to associate each ID to a specific date, example: X Worker has break from the 21st of January till the 29th, I'll have to tell the code to associate the first ID to its own start and end date or I assume thats what I have to do. I'm a complete begginer to HTML, PHP, SQL and JS coding hence why I do not know exactly how it works.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. SQL will automatically print the contents of each row which matches the query criteria. So if you wrote `SELECT id, DATEDIFF(start, end) as total FROM events` for example, it will print the matching ID for each row next to the totals (assuming an `id` column exists in your table. Or you could do it with `title` for example, or any of the other columns. I think you need to study some SQL basics, maybe).

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely give SQL a good read next month to get used to it, this code you just gave me works perfectly for my need. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
I think this could do it :

```
INSERT INTO events (title, name, color, start, end, total) 
SELECT :title, :name, :color, t.start, t.end, DATEDIFF(t.start, t.end) )
FROM ( SELECT :start, :end) AS t
```

But you'll need to try to be sure.

Comment: you can't use the same parameter name twice in PDO... also, aren't you going to explain _why_ your version is better? That would make a much more useful answer.

Comment: @ADyson ah sh*, did too much PL recently, totally forgot, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson better than ? the OP request ? it should work ; your answer ? I don't think it's better, just different ;) I put a bit more logic on the SQL side, you put it on the PHP : didn't make a big difference. (And Ii don't see any big answer really useful)

Comment: better than the OP's code - i.e. explain what you changed and why it fixes the issue. A code dump on its own is not useful for someone who didn't understand their mistake in the first place... and I was commenting on your original version, don't forget, not your altered SQL. Whether your code is "better" than mine is for the OP to decide, not me. I'm talking about the overall quality of your post. I'm trying to encourage you to make it more useful by adding some explanatory notes - it's not intended as simply criticism for its own sake.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Blag, this code has the same problem as Adyson's and it's probably related to the way I set my JS code, I'll look into this further.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the Values clause and the Select clause in one insert statement.
You have two alternatives:

```
$query_event = "INSERT INTO events (title, name, color, start, end, total) "
        . "VALUES (:title, :name, :color, :start, :end, DATEDIFF(':start', ':end')) "
```

```
$query_event = "INSERT INTO events (title, name, color, start, end, total) "
        . "SELECT :title, :name, :color, :start, :end, DATEDIFF(':start', ':end') AS total from dual";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. I used the second one, it is able to insert but it prints total as either a 0 when the type is set to int or an empty string. It perhaps may have some to do with my date format? It is set as follows: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Comment: Datediff gives the number of days. This can be 0. You can also use timediff which gives the time between start and end in hours

Comment: That's right, but let's say that start = 2020-02-10 and end = 2020-02-15, the time difference should either be 5 or -5 depending on how you set the code up. This is not the case for me, not matter the length difference between the two dates the result will always be 0 for some reason. I'll look into this further, thanks for the time!